# How can I access request object in the loopback operational hooks?

Tags: javascript, express, strongloop, loopback

I'm using loopback 3.x and I've written an [Access Hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Operation-hooks.html#access). I want to add some condition on the basis of [User Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

So I'm willing to access Request > Headers > User-Agent.

Is it even possible to access it? if no then is there any other way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to this using [Remote hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html).

```js
ModelName.beforeRemote('findById', (ctx, data, next) => {
     // ctx has req object that further contains the headers and my work is done
})
```

**But still I'm opening the question for the further question if it is possible to do in the access hooks**